# Search not remembering accessed network folders on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is it normal for Windows 10 to not remember I accessed a network folder when I search for it?

See the picture bellow. That's on Windows 7. I typed that location on Start Menu and entered the credentials. Then Start Menu memorizes it until I reboot the computer.

[image]

I've cut the image to take less space, but that's Start Menu. Now on Windows 10, that option doesn't appear. It has no idea I already went there, and makes me always write the network location.

Any help on this is appreciated. If it helps, I'm running LTSC 2019 edition (build 1809).

Comment: Is your search set to search for "Apps", "Documents", "Web", or "All"?

Comment: Where do I see that? Hopefully that's not Cortana's settings. I didn't mention I'm using LTSC edition, so it's not installed (in case I'm meant to select that there).

Comment: You actually didn’t mention that.  You just said you were using 1809

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't know it was important to mention. I've now put it there.

Comment: It’s only important since Cortana and Windows Search will be locked to 1809 answers instead of more recent versions

Comment: Well, any answer for any version will be appreciated anyways. Might work here too. Or at least maybe helps someone else. I don't know if this is supposed to happen on new builds of Windows 10.

Comment: An answer that is appropriate for 1903+ won’t work for 1809.  Windows Search and Cortana got numerous improvements since 1903 through 20H2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally accessed the shares with Windows+R Run prompt and they appeared on the Start Menu. No idea if this happens with other versions of Win10 or 11 or whatever, but running with the Run prompt once will make them stay on the Start Menu until a reboot is issued, like in Windows 7.